# Обновить / добавить из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, sqlite

В базе данных имеется две таблицы `table_A` и `table_B`.

`table_A:`

```
id |  Vendor |   Model     |   Size    | Type 
 1 |  ASUS   |   A68HM     | Micro-ATX | AMD
 2 | GIGABIT | GA-A320M-S2 | Micro-ATX | AMD
 3 |   MSI   | A320M PRO-E | Micro-ATX | AMD
```

`table_B:`

```
 id | Vendor  | Model  
  1 | Biostar | A68MHE
  2 | ASRock  | A320M-DVS
  3 | ASRock  | H110M-DGS
  4 |  MSI    | A320M PRO-E
```

Необходимо забрать данные из `table_B` и поместить в `table_A`, сравнивая значения по столбцу `Model`, если в `table_A` есть такая модель - не добавлять запись, нету модели - добавить строку. В итоге должно быть на выходе так `table_A`:

```
id |  Vendor |     Model    |   Size    | Type 
 1 |  ASUS   |     A68HM    | Micro-ATX | AMD
 2 | GIGABIT |  GA-A320M-S2 | Micro-ATX | AMD
 3 |   MSI   |  A320M PRO-E | Micro-ATX | AMD
 4 | Biostar |     A68MHE   |           |     
 5 | ASRock  |   A320M-DVS  |           |    
 6 | ASRock  |   H110M-DGS  |           |
```

Пытался реализовать запросом:

```
INSERT INTO table_A (Model, Vendor) 
SELECT Model, Vendor FROM table_B
WHERE Model NOT IN (SELECT Model FROM table_A)
```

Пишет, что `0` записей изменено.

Что не так, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да вроде должно работать. Скорее всего ошибка какая-то банальная. Как именно таблицы называются: `А` и `Б` или `table_A` и `table_B`?

Comment: Таблицы называются как указано в запросе, т.е. `table_A` и `table_B`, сейчас поправлю в примере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как говориться: Не прошло и пол года.
Вроде такой запрос работает хорошо:

```
INSERT INTO table_A (Model, Vendor) 
SELECT table_B.Model, table_B.Vendor FROM table_B
WHERE table_B.Model NOT IN 
(SELECT Model FROM table_A WHERE Model IS NOT NULL)
```